# Python: Print when error occurs and when it disappears

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, exception

I have a web scraping script that checks four sites once a minute and posts to twitter if any of the given keywords are present. If ConnectionError occurs, it sleeps for a minute and then tries again. I would like it to print "No internet connection" the first time the error occurs but not the second time if the error is still present when it tries again one minute later. I would also like it to print "Internet connection established" the first time it does not get a ConnectionError after previously having the Connection error. Here I would also like it to only print one time. How should I code this? I have this so far:

```
def checksite():
    try:
        *extensive irrelevant code for web scraping and posting*

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print("No internet connection")

while True:
    checksite()
    sleep(60)
```

This does however print every time is is not able to connect to the internet.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Keep a variable with a certain state somewhere. E.g. `was_able_to_connect_last_time = True/False`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```py
NoInternet = 0
def checksite():
    try:
        *extensive irrelevant code for web scraping and posting*
        if NoInternet == 1:
           print("Internet connection established")
           NoInternet = 0

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        if NoInternet == 0:
             print("No internet connection")
             NoInternet += 1 

while True:
    checksite()
    sleep(60)
```

But you have to check the tabs

Comment: There is a capital N in the name of the variable line 1 but no capital N later (I can't edit to fix only one letter unfortunately :/). Also, I think booleans are probably clearer than integers in this case.

Comment: Oh yes Thanks You !

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I get the following error: 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'NoInternet' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could look like this, where `checksite` returns the status of the internet connection instead of printing (leaving the printing logic to the loop):

```
def checksite():
    try:
        # *extensive irrelevant code for web scraping and posting*
        return True

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        return False

was_connected = False
while True:
    connected = checksite()
    if connected and not was_connected:
        print("Internet connection established")
    elif not connected and was_connected:
        print("No internet connection")
    was_connected = connected
    sleep(60)
```